# Creating a custom Popular Category Grid using foreach

Tags: magento-1.9, category, grid

I am working on a custom category grid on CMS home page, and unable to get it in form.
I have done trying using loopbreak with custom width and height, but didn't get any success or i don't know about its usages.

After trying loopbreak i thought of doing this with bootstrap can help me out but my bad luck or lack of knowledge, i cant get it in form through foreach.

If there is any other way to get it done, any help will be appreciated.

here is the image for an idea.
[image]

i m using magento 1.9.2.3 with php 5.2.0, thanks in advance for help.

Lalit

Comment: what if category-4 is in full height, (like category-5) ? what will be the design ?

Comment: @AnilSuthar thanks for the reply,  here we have 7 categories if we put category-4 to full height then surely we have to put one more category to full height, i just want to put category 5 to full height.